# UserDefaults.standard.set() not working on watchOS only

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

I have a watchOS only app (not my first) and using `UserDefaults.standard.set()` to store some data. In my other project it is working fine but in this project it do not store anything. Values to store are present (Array). Even after triggering `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` which is not needed on my other app it do not work. Any suggestions on which factors it can be possible to not work?

After rebuilding / running the app from XCode the data is gone.

Just saving like that

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.data, forKey: "fetchData")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Where `self.data` is an `Array` with items of type `Dictionary<String,Any>` (Int and Date get stored)

Comment: Just wondering because this happened to me: Are you resetting `fetchData` somewhere else? Like once your app is launched?

Comment: Nope – definitely not. Super short code. Just appending / setting data as shown above.